# Creating indicator variable in Stata

Tags: stata, data-manipulation

In a panel data set I have 3 variables: `name`, `week`, and `income`.

I would like to make an indicator variable that indicates initial weeks where `income` is 0. So say a person X has 0 `income` in the first 13 weeks, the indicator takes the value 1 the first 13 weeks, and is otherwise 0. The same procedure for person Y and so on.

I have tried using by groups, but I can't get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should always show code attempts, including failed code. Many people won't answer questions without code, and we have no scope for explaining your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is

```
bysort name (week) : gen no_income = sum(income) == 0
```

The function `sum()` yields cumulative or running sum. So, as long as `income` is 0, its cumulative sum remains 0 too. As soon as a person earns something, the cumulative sum becomes positive. The code is based on the presumption that cumulative income can not cross zero again because in a given week, `income` is negative. To exclude that possibility use an appropriate extra condition, such as

```
bysort name (week) : gen no_income = sum(income) == 0 & income == 0
```

For a problem with very similar flavour, see [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/dropping-spells-of-missing-values/index.html). A meta-lesson is to look at the StataCorp FAQs as one of several resources.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. Say I also wanted to flag observations where `income` is constant for more than say four weeks. How could one structure such code?

Comment: That's a new question, but look for spells of constant value. Discussion of principles at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0029 and a dedicated command available by `ssc inst tsspell`.

Comment: Alternatively if you generate the cumulative sum of income, then it is necessary but not sufficient that the cumulative sum be equal to its value four weeks ago. And so forth.